# How to connect Power BI market place chart with Slicers?

Tags: powerbi

I want to see if when I am clicking on any place on the chart the slicers value also changes but when clicking on chart the changes don't get reflect on slicers.

Answer (score 0):

Puneet,

You will control this using the 'Edit Interactions' control in the 'Format' ribbon of the 'Visual Tools' menu.  This is a context menu that is only available when you have a visual focused.

[image]

The way you use this is to first select your chart visualization.  Then navigate to the Format ribbon under Visual Tools and select 'Edit interactions.'  Once you click this button, you'll notice some icons appear over all other visuals and slicers on the page.

[image]

For each of your slicers, select the filter icon.  Click the 'Edit interactions' button again to exit 'Edit interactions' mode.  Now your slicers will be filtered based on the filter context that has been applied to your chart.